# set default image from static img src if no image is uploaded to post

Tags: php, laravel, image, post

I am trying to set a static image that would be applied to the post images/thumbs if there`s no image uploaded trough backend.

I am using laravel with crudboster

my img src code: `<img src="{{$post->image}}" alt="">`

i dont understand very well the php and coding, but based on that code above, which display the image when uploaded, what else i can try?

do i need to do something in the img src tag, or this has to be done trough laravel coding?

Please note that i`m looking for the simplest option

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem? Details more

Comment: `{{ $post->image ?? "no-image.png" }}` if `$post->image` id null/undefined then it will show _no-image.png_

Comment: Thank STA, i`ll try this in my img src tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP 7** has added a new operator double question mark (**??**) operator. In PHP 7, the double question mark(**??**) operator known as **Null Coalescing Operator**.

It returns its first operand if it exists and is `not NULL`, otherwise, it returns its second operand. It evaluates from left to right. **Null Coalescing operator** also can be used in a chain format :

```
{{ $post->image ?? "no-image.png" }}
```

Here, If `$post->image` id `null/undefined` then it will show `no-image.png` as output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement like this:

```
@if($post->image)
<img src="{{$post->image}}" alt="">
@else
<img src="path/to/image/name.jpg" alt="">
@endif
```

Comment: Hey Oana, thanks for your reply. Would i just go like this: <img src="@if($post->image)
<img src="{{$post->image}}" alt="">
@else
<img src="path/to/image/name.jpg" alt="">
@endif"  or where should i put the cod.

Comment: Oana, i tried the STA`s answer which worked perfectly